# Delphi TCPClient Issue

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, delphi-xe4

I am new to Delphi and trying to convert vb.net apps to learn. The issue I am having is reading from a TCP/IP host. Currently I can connect via telnet to the device, send a command, and the device will send data non-stop until all data is sent. This could be simply two characters followed by CR/LF, or it could be several rows of varing length data. Each row is end is CR/LF. Prior to writing code, we were able to telnet via Hyperterminal to the device. Send a command, and, with the capture text enabled save to a text file.

Below is the code I have so far. I have not coded for saving to text file (one step at a time). The data is pipe delimited. I have no control on the format or operatation of the device aside from sending commands and receiving data. It works most of the time however there are times when not all of the data (65 records for testing) are received. I will greatly appreciate guidence and feel free to comment on my code, good or bad.

```
function Parse(Char, S: string; Count: Integer): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  T: string;
begin
  if S[Length(S)] <> Char then
    S := S + Char;
  for I := 1 to Count do
  begin
    T := Copy(S, 0, Pos(Char, S) - 1);
    S := Copy(S, Pos(Char, S) + 1, Length(S));
  end;
  Result := T;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnEXITClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if idTcpClient1.connected then
begin
  idTcpClient1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.clear;
  idTcpClient1.Disconnect;
end;
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSendDataClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  mTXDataString : String;
  RXString : String;

begin
  IdTCPClient1.Host := IPAddress.Text;
  IdTCPClient1.Port := StrToInt(IPPort.Text);

  mTXDataString := mTXData.Text + #13#10;

    IdTCPClient1.Connect;

    If IdTCPClient1.Connected then
    begin

      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(mTXDataString);

      mTXDataString := mTXData.Lines.Text;

      if MTXDataString.Contains('SCHEMA') then
      begin
        mRXData.Lines.Add(IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn);
        while not (IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty) do
        begin
          RXString := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn;
          If (RXString <> '') and (RXString <> '??') then
          begin
            //Add received data to RXmemo
            mRXData.Lines.Add(RXString);
            //Determine number of records to received based on schema data
            lblRecords.Caption := Parse(',', RXString, 2);

          end;
        end;  //while not
      end     // if

      else
      if mTXDataString.Contains('DATA') then
      begin
        mRXData.Lines.Add(IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn);
        while not (IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty) do
        begin
          RXString := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn;
          If (RXString <> '') and (RXString <> '??') then
          begin
            mRXData.Lines.Add(RXString);
          end;  // if
        end;    //while not

      end;  // if Schema or not

    end; // if Connected

    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;

    end; //Procedure
```

Answer (score 0):

HyperTerminal and Telnet apps display whatever data they receive, in real-time.  `TIdTCPClient` is not a real-time component.  You control when and how it reads.  If you are expecting data to arrive asynchronously, especially if you don't know how many rows are going to be received, then you need to perform the reading in a timer or worker thread, eg:

```
procedure TForm2.TimerElapsed(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler = nil then Exit;
  if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(50);
    if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  S := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  // use S as needed ...
end;
```

Or:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    fClient: TIdTCPClient;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(aClient: TIdTCPClient);
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(aClient: TIdTCPClient);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  fClient := aClient;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  S: String;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    S := fClient.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    // use S as needed ...
  end;
end;
```

Or, if the server supports the actual Telnet protocol, have a look at using Indy's `TIdTelnet` component instead.

Comment: thank you for guidence.  I did pursue the TIdTelnet component but after reading several posts it was my understanding the componentdoes not behave like a traditional telnet application. is that true? I will read more of documentation on the indy client also. the server does support telnet protocol.